# Change default permission from 'Consumer' to 'Collaborator' when joining a site

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Now all users can join in a public site by searching the site and then clicking **Join** button.
User will get added to the site with the default permission '**Consumer**'.

How can I change the default permission from **'Consumer' to 'Collaborator'**?

Can I change this default permission by editing any xml/properties file?

I am using Alfresco version 4.2.c.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a client side JavaScript file **site-finder.js** in which there is a method doJoin which you'll need to change.

Snippet:

```
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPut(
         {
            url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "api/sites/" + site.shortName + "/memberships",
            dataObj:
            {
               role: "SiteConsumer",
               person:
               {
                  userName: user
               }
            },
.................
```

Just change the SiteConsumer to SiteCollaborator and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi Tahir, thanks for the reply.
I tried your suggestion, but which is not working.
I changed 'role: "SiteCollaborator"' as mentioned above, still user is adding to Consumer group.

Comment: I suspect there's something else validating that, otherwise everyone could become Managers of public sites just by tweaking their client side JS and requesting to join...

Comment: You can locate the repo webscript and see how it gets the role and maybe there is a check. Sure SiteManager would be a security issue, but anything else should be oke.

Comment: And you'll probably will also need to set the membership repo webscript to authentication runas=admin (maybe this part is enough)